# How to make columns different colors in an ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting

Consider an `ArrayPlot` of some arbitrary matrix with values between zero and one.

```
matrix = {
          {0.1, 0.1, 0.1}
        , {0.3, 0.3, 0.3}
        , {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
      };
```

I want to plot this matrix as an `ArrayPlot` but with each Column as a different color.

Using `ColorFunction` and `Lighter` I can make all the Columns the same color.

```
matrix = {{0.1, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.3, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}};
ArrayPlot[matrix, ColorFunction -> (Lighter[Red, #] &)]
```

[image]

## Question:

> **How do I make each Column of the `ArrayPlot` shades of a different color?**

For instance, I would like to make the cells of the first column shades of blue.

Answer (score 5):

```
 MatrixPlot[MapIndexed[Lighter[ColorData[97][#2[[2]]], #] &, matrix, {2}]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
MatrixPlot[MapIndexed[Lighter[{Red, Blue, Green}[[#2[[2]]]], #] &, matrix, {2}]]
```

[image]

```
MatrixPlot[MapIndexed[
  Lighter[ColorData["Rainbow"][(#2[[2]] - 1)/(Dimensions[matrix][[2]] - 1)], #] &, 
  matrix, {2}]]
```

[image]

You can also use [`Raster`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster.html) + [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html):

```
Graphics[Raster[MapIndexed[List @@ Lighter[{Red, Blue, Green}[[#2[[2]]]], #] &, 
    Reverse @ matrix, {2}]],
  Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{#, #} &@({# - .5, 4 - #} & /@ Range[3]), 
   {#, #} &@({# - .5, #} & /@ Range[3])}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `ArrayPlot` accepts a matrix of color swatches.

[image]

So one way of achieving the desired result is to replace all of the elements of the matrix with corresponding swatches. This can be done using the `Lighter` function

```
matrix = {{0.1, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.3, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}};
trans = Transpose[matrix];
swatchMatrix = Transpose[{
                           Lighter[ Red, #] & /@ trans[[1]]
                         , Lighter[ Blue, #] & /@ trans[[2]]
                         , Lighter[ Green, #] & /@ trans[[3]]
               }];

ArrayPlot[swatchMatrix]
```